# wpf datatrigger + value binding

Tags: wpf

I have a custom component that should change your alignment as a property of the window changes and getting the value of another property of itself. The property of the window is changing correctly, however, the alignment of the component is not changing. The converter that returns the alignment is also working correctly (it returns Left, Right or Center, depending on the other property of the component). So where is the error? Here is the code of the DataTrigger:

```
<myComponent.Resources>
    <lib:HorizontalAlignmentConverter x:Key="HorizontalAlignmentConverter"/>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type myComponent}" x:Key="HorizontalAligner">    
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=MainWindow1, Path=myWindowResizedProperty}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="{Binding Path=myOtherProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource HorizontalAlignmentConverter}}"/> 
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</myComponent.Resources>
```

Thanks in advance!

Another question: Is there any way I can reference, in the expression of DataTrigger Binding, the Window object, without using his name? This way would be more generic.

Thanks again!

Comment: should there be a distinction between HorizontalAlignment and HorizontalContentAlignment? ...can you set alignment manually and get expected results?

Comment: I'm just using HorizontalAlignment. When I set it manually I get the expected results.

Comment: Any suggestions? Thanks!